# unable to resolve the error of ClassCastException

Tags: android, sqlite

Using the radio button I am trying to change the activity.

This is the main activity

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    String selection = "";

    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radioButton1:
        Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Personal.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton2:
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }

}
```

The radio button 2 is working fine but when I click on radio button 1, I am unable to open the activity. 
The button 1 activity contain

```
SQLiteDatabase db1 = null;
private static String DBNAME = "PERSONAL.db";
Button save, cancel, check ;
EditText name, price = null;
Editable d1, d2 = null;
TextView txt = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal);


    cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(Personal.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    db1 = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            d1 = name.getText();
            d2 = price.getText();

            try
            {
                db1.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personal_data(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name VARCHAR, Price INTEGER); ");
                db1.execSQL("INSERT INTO personal_data (Name,Price)  VALUES ('"+d1+"','"+d2+"');");

                name.setText("");
                price.setText("");
                Cursor c = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM personal_data", null);

                if(c!= null){
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {

                            String name =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
                            String price =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Price"));

                            System.out.println(name);
                            System.out.println(price);


                        }
                        while(c.moveToNext());
                    }

                    Integer a =  c.getCount();
                    System.out.println(a);

                }


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);


            }


        }
    });

    check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.view);
    check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            txt.setText(d1+""+d2);
            String s = (String)txt.getText();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    });
```

and here is the error I am getting.
Log cat

```
02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.my_expenses/com.example.my_expenses.Personal}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468):at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button
02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468):at com.example.my_expenses.Personal.onCreate(Personal.java:46)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468):at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

02-21 11:43:21.939: E/AndroidRuntime(9468):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

I tried cleaning the project, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: i think you are casting button on the place of radiobutton

Comment: What is line number 46 in personal.java

Comment: error in this line  price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cancel); Cancel is a button you try to change as edittext

Comment: can you post your xml file. Or just check if you have declared "cancel" as button only in xml as well?

Comment: post your xml also and tell me is cancel and save button define in xml?

Comment: show me your xml layout code.

Comment: oh yes.. Thanks for the error appu bala :)

Answer (score 0):

You have used cast two times for R.id.cancel Please check your layout xml what exactly it is..

cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);

price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cancel);